# My CJK punctuation sits in a margin

Tags: xetex, indentation, punctuation, cjk, xecjk

I'm trying to forge a macro to produce nice formatting for pairs of sample Japanese sentences and their translation, but I seem to have run into a problem with indentation.

If I have a hard line break (`\\`) and the following line starts with the opening quote 「, the quote gets negatively indented into the margin. There's actually nothing wrong with this -- hanging punctuation is normal and desirable in Japanese typography -- but the first line's *does not* get the same hanging indent.

How do I get these quotation marks aligned?

(I'd prefer to have them aligned the same as the western quotation marks that come right below. The relevant negative indent removed altogether, I think.)

```
 % good
    「疲れたか」
    「いいや、ちっとも」
   　"Are you tired?"
   　"No, not at all."

 % bad
    「疲れたか」
   「いいや、ちっとも」
   　"Are you tired?"
   　"No, not at all."
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\newcommand{\example}[2]
{\medbreak%
\begingroup% make parindent change local
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}%
#1
\par\textit{#2}%
\endgroup%
\medbreak}



% some sample sentences for testing the macro
% taken from tanaka corpus, except the haiku

\newcommand{\mkex}{%
\example
{青いスーツ、白いシャツ、赤いネクタイが男性従業員全員の必需品だ。}
{A blue suit, white shirt and red tie are essential for all male workers.}

\example
{「疲れたか」\\「いいや、ちっとも」}
{``Are you tired?'' \\ ``No, not at all.''}

\example
{コンタクトすると目が乾いた感じになって、目が赤くなります。}
{When I use contacts my eyes feel dry and become red.}

\example
{「寝てた？」\\
「爆睡」\\
「そ、そうか？」\\
「なんかうなされてたよ。怖い夢でも見てた？」}
{``I fell asleep?'' \\
``Totally.'' \\
``Really?'' \\
``You were very restless, did you have a scary dream?''}

\example
{ネクタイを締める間、ちょっとじっとしてね。}
{Hold still a moment while I fix your tie.}

\example
{花火の弾ける音が止むと、急に辺りが静かになる。後に残った火薬の匂いが、なんだか俺をセンチメンタルな気分にさせた。}
{As the popping sound of the fireworks stopped, it suddenly became quiet
around me. The smell of gunpowder somehow put me in a sentimental mood.}

\example
{古池や \\
蛙飛び込む \\
水の音}
{old pond\ldots \\
a frog leaps in \\
water's sound}

\example
{ウィルソンの解法は、同じ定数を使用したという点でハドソンのものと類似している。}
{Wilson's solution is similar to Hudson's in that they used the same constants.}

\example
{人の出会いなんて、なんだかんだ、最初のインパクトで５０％以上は決まってしまっている。}
{When people meet, first impressions determine more than 50 percent of whatever
happens next.}

\example
{「なんだか焦げ臭いね」\\
「うっかりパンを黒こげにしちゃったの」}
{``Can you smell something burning?'' \\
``Oh, I went and burnt the toast.''}
}



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\mkex

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

My texlive is somewhat dated (2009), so if newer versions behave differently, I'd like to know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My chrystal ball says: Update to TeXLive 2014 (as a general remark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using the latest TeX Live 2014 (with `xeCJK` 2014/06/20 v3.2.13), there is no error.

It is [a very old bug](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=114) of `xeCJK`, and is roughly fixed since TeX Live 2013 (with `xeCJK` 2013/05/28 v3.2.1). There may be still some special situations that `xeCJK` cannot handle well, but you can hardly meet the issue now.

Anyway, it is always preferred to use an empty line to start a new paragraph rather than break the line with `\\`.

Comment: It is [issue 114](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=114) and some derivative revisions.

Comment: I upgraded to texlive 2013 (I think; whatever's included with ubuntu 14.04) and it seems to indeed fix the problem.

Comment: I originally settled on `\\` because it seemed to suppress indentation (but it currently seems unnecessary since I suppressed it through other means). I tried to start new paragraphs (empty line or `\par`) as you suggested but just got compilation errors; but that's probably material for a new question.